# Can an ARIMAX estimate this model?

Tags: arima, data-generating-process

So I have this AR data series, AR1, mostly (for the argument). I also have an exogeneous regressor, only the DGP I suspect is something in the line of:
$ y_t=y_{t-1}+\alpha x_ty_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t $

Can an ARIMAX estimate this? What's the specification? If not, what?

Comment: Your equation does not have an error term, so $y_t$ is a deterministic function of $y_{t-1}$ and $x_t$. Is that right? Regardless of that, this is not within the class of ARIMAX.

Comment: Meant the stochastic version. Will use AR(1). Thank you Richard

Answer (score 1):

A simple ARIMAX(1,0,0) should be of the form $y_t = α_1y_{t-1} + α_2x_t + e_t$. From your question it seems that is what you wanted to write, isn't it?

As @Richard pointed out, the equation you wrote is not an ARIMAX, but solving it would give $log(y_t/y_{t-1}) ≈ αx_t$, which a different but well known type of model. Please, clarify.

Comment: Yeah, I mean the stochastic version. Thank you very much :)